# Show that ${n \choose k}$ $p^{k(k-1)/2}$ $=$ $\Theta$ $(n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2})$

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that ${n \choose k}$ $p^{k(k-1)/2}$ $=$ $\Theta$$(n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2})$ (for $n$$\rightarrow$$\infty$) where $p$$\in$$[0,1]$ and $k$ is a positive integer. I was able to show that ${n \choose k}$$p^{k(k-1)/2}$$=$$O$$(n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2})$ but I am having difficulty showing $(n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2})$$=$$O$${n \choose k}$$p^{k(k-1)/2}$.

This has come up in a probability course when trying to find a threshold function for $G(n,p)$ to contain a $k$-clique. If there are more suitable tags for this problem then please add them.

Comment: Does it suffices to show $\binom{n}{k} \in \Theta(n^k)$? We have $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{1} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n - k + 1}{k} \le \frac{n^k}{k!} \le n^k$.

Comment: I might be missing something here. I am trying to show $(n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2})$$=$$O$${n \choose k}$$p^{k(k-1)/2}$. To do that I started by considering $\limsup_n$$\frac{n^{k}p^{k(k-1)/2}}{{n \choose k}p^{k(k-1)/2}}$= $\limsup_n$$\frac{n^{k}}{{n \choose k}}$. Does ${n \choose k}$$\leq$$n^{k}$ help show that this limit is less than $\infty$?

Comment: It only shows that the limsup is greater or equal to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we are looking at the asymptotic behaviour when $n$ tends toward infinity, we don't care about the term $p^{k(k-1)/2}$.
Thus we only need to show that $\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix} = \Theta(n^k)$.

You already proved that ${n \choose k} = O\begin{pmatrix}n^{k} \end{pmatrix}$.
Let us prove the other way.

For this, we shall prove that there exist $c > 0, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n^k \leq c \begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix},\ \forall n \geq n_0$.

Let $n_0=2k$.
Then, $\forall n \geq n_0$
$$\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (n-i)}{k!} \geq  \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} n/2}{k!} = \frac{n^k}{2^k k!} = \frac{1}{c}n^k,$$
where $c = 2^k k!$ is independant of $n$.

Thus, we proved that $\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix} = \Theta(n^k)$.